# Chunk Loaders In Vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am creating a custom map in Minecraft, but when I try to set a block, I get the error, "Cannot place block outside of the world." I do believe that this is due to chunks not loading. Is there any kind of Vanilla Chunk Loader that I can use to keep many chunks loaded at the same time? I would prefer if there was no clutter.

I have heard about the Hopper system (I don;t know if it stills works, but then again, it creates too much clutter.

Comment: There are ways to keep chunks loaded, and ways to load unloaded chunks, but not really anything that's less "clutter" than the hopper method.

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but I've had success in the past using `/spreadplayers` to teleport a mob to the location and load these chunks, then immediately running `/setblock`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find your spawn chunks, they are always loaded in Minecraft worlds, it is possible to put a block outside of the world if unloaded, but the spawn chunks are always loaded.